# Elasticsearch install custom plugins results in ERROR: `elasticsearch` directory is missing in the plugin zip

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

When I try to install the plugin I built by calling

```
./elasticsearch-plugin install file:///fullpath/to/zipfile/custome_plugin.zip
```

It gives me this error:

```
ERROR: `elasticsearch` directory is missing in the plugin zip
```

I was reading some other similar posts and many tried to install a .jar instead of .zip. I did try installing .zip, but this same error still shows.

Additionally (might not be related to this issue), when I manually unzip the zip file and put it into plugin folder, doing `elasticsearch-plugins list` does list out the custom plugin. In this case the plugin is a custom analyzer, but somehow the mapping doesn't recognize the analyzer. Is it because I did not install it properly?

EDIT:

adding a little info, when I shut down the cluster and then restart after the plugin is manually unzipped and put into the `plugin` directory, the cluster wouldn't start. I got error that looks like

```
[2017-08-31T11:15:52,668][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] fatal error in thread [main], exiting
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/index/analysis/AnalysisModule$AnalysisBinderProcessor
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:423) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:387) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:140) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:312) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:244) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:232) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:232) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:351) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:114) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:67) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisModule$AnalysisBinderProcessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:814) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    ... 19 more
```

It seems like this Analysis

Is there some library I'm missing?

EDIT 2:
After some more digging, I found this site

http://snacktrace.com/artifacts/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/1.7.3/org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisModule$AnalysisBinderProcessor$AnalyzersBindings

Seems like this `AnalyzersBindings` is only for ES 1.x and 2.x (<2.4)? I need a way to replace this.

EDIT 3:
As requested, here's how AnalyzerBinding is used originally

```
package org.elasticsearch.plugin.analysis.my.analyzer;

import org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisModule;

public class AnalyzerBinderProcessor extends AnalysisModule.AnalysisBinderProcessor {

    @Override
    public void processAnalyzers(AnalyzersBindings analyzersBindings) {
        analyzersBindings.processAnalyzer("my_name", AnalyzerProvider.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void processTokenFilters(TokenFiltersBindings tokenFiltersBindings) {
    }
}
```

then in my AnalyzerPlugin.java I have

```
public class AnalyzerPlugin extends Plugin {
    //some other code here that's not related to Binder 

    public void onModule(AnalysisModule module) {
        module.addProcessor(new AnalyzerBinderProcessor());
    }
}
```

EDIT 4: this is neverending.......

if I keep the @Override, it throws

```
[ERROR] /opt/bg/analytics/src/java/src/analyzer5.0/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/plugin/analysis/my_analyzer/AnalyzerPlugin.java:[16,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

Also, facing an issue of

```
[ERROR] /opt/bg/analytics/src/java/src/analyzer5.0/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/plugin/analysis/my_analyzer/AnalyzerPlugin.java:[36,17] onModule(org.elasticsearch.indices.analysis.AnalysisModule) in org.elasticsearch.plugin.analysis.my_analyzer.AnalyzerPlugin cannot override onModule(org.elasticsearch.indices.analysis.AnalysisModule) in org.elasticsearch.plugins.Plugin
```

because `overridden method is final`

Is that an update from old `Plugin` to new? I'm so lost......

I feel like I need a thorough tutorial of how to create a plugin for custom analyzer, all I can find so far is this

http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2016/10/16/creating-a-plugin-for-elasticsearch-5-dot-0-using-maven-updated-for-ga/

which doesn't help much. Does anyone have a good link?

Comment: Is the plugin u trying to install a site-plugin ? As of version 5.0 , elasticsearch doesn't support site plugins any more so this will not work , check this https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-site-plugins-with-elasticsearch-5-0 .

Comment: @skm It's not. It's a custom analyzer. I got it from legacy code and it was for 2.0 I'm trying to build it for 5.0. The analyzer builds when I `mvn package`, but it doesn't integrate well 9or can't install) on 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, in ES 5.x we have `org.elasticsearch.plugins.AnalysisPlugin`, which is the main point for creating custom analysis components. You need to adapt your plugin code, so you could register whatever custom analyzer/tokenizer/etc you have.

Example of the plugin, that should do the trick for you:

```
public class MyAnalyzerPlugin implements AnalysisPlugin {

@Override
public Map<String, AnalysisModule.AnalysisProvider<AnalyzerProvider<? extends Analyzer>>> getAnalyzers() {
    final Map<String, AnalysisModule.AnalysisProvider<AnalyzerProvider<? extends Analyzer>>> objectObjectHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    objectObjectHashMap.put("my_analyzer", new MyAnalyzerProviderFactory());
    return objectObjectHashMap;
}

class MyAnalyzerProviderFactory implements AnalysisModule.AnalysisProvider<AnalyzerProvider<?>> {

    private final MyAnalyzerProvider analyzerProvider;

    public MyAnalyzerProviderFactory() {
        analyzerProvider = new MyAnalyzerProvider(AnalyzerScope.INDICES);
    }

    public AnalyzerProvider<?> create(String name, Settings settings) {
        Version indexVersion = Version.indexCreated(settings);
        if (!Version.CURRENT.equals(indexVersion)) {
            PreBuiltAnalyzers preBuiltAnalyzers = PreBuiltAnalyzers.getOrDefault(name, null);
            if (preBuiltAnalyzers != null) {
                Analyzer analyzer = preBuiltAnalyzers.getAnalyzer(indexVersion);
                return new MyAnalyzerProvider(AnalyzerScope.INDICES);
            }
        }

        return analyzerProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public AnalyzerProvider<?> get(IndexSettings indexSettings, Environment environment, String name, Settings settings)
            throws IOException {
        return create(name, settings);
    }

    public Analyzer analyzer() {
        return analyzerProvider.get();
    }
}


class MyAnalyzerProvider implements AnalyzerProvider<StandardAnalyzer> {

    private final StandardAnalyzer analyzer;
    private final AnalyzerScope scope;

    public MyAnalyzerProvider(AnalyzerScope scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
        this.analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    }

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "my-standard-analyzer";
    }

    @Override
    public AnalyzerScope scope() {
        return scope;
    }

    @Override
    public StandardAnalyzer get() {
        return analyzer;
    }
}
```

Of course, you need to adapt your Analyzer as well, since Lucene version has been changed and some API may be deprecated or removed.

Comment: Thanks for the help (great user name btw), I think  my main issue is `AnalyzersBindings` which doesn't exist anymore. Our legacy code has an entire file utilizing this. I've been comparing the old and new version of the analyzers provided in ES (ex. icu) to see what they changed when they get to 5.x. So far I haven't found the linkage. You got any experience with that?

Comment: please check EDIT 3 in my post

Comment: so, instead of module.addProcessor(new AnalyzerBinderProcessor()); you need to do module.registerAnalyzer("my-analyzer-name", MyAnalyzer::new); and you do not need analyzerbinder at all

Comment: nvm, still have issue with this. Can you take a look of EDIT 4?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you already have fixed your error.

However, I thought I would add my learning in case there are people who are getting `ERROR: 'elasticsearch' directory is missing in the plugin zip` becasue of the same mistake that I made.

As it is stated in Elasticsearch documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugin-authors.html), the folder name of the plugin should be "elasticsearch" before the folder is compressed to a zip file.

So, regardless of the zip file's name like "elasticsearch-analysis-mecab-ko-5.5.3.0.zip", the plugin folder before compressed should be called "elasticsearch". If the folder name is not "elasticsearch", when you run elasticsearch-plugin install, your elasticsearch simply gives you `ERROR: 'elasticsearch' directory is missing in the plugin zip`

Thus, after you make or amend your custom plugin folder, compress it:

`$ zip -r elasticsearch-analysis-mecab-ko-5.5.3.0.zip elasticsearch`

then install the plugin

`$ ./elasticsearch-plugin install file:///Users/btaek/Desktop/ElasticSearch/elasticsearch-analysis-mecab-ko-5.5.3.0.zip`

Comment: I had the same problem, but my zip file was available through http. I downloaded it and opened it up, but there was the directory 'elasticsearch'. So then I tried installing it from the downloaded zip and had no problem. I don't know why it won't work with http, but I'm putting it here just in case others have the same problem.